# ORMLite update of the database

Tags: android, database, ormlite

I'm actually developing an app which is using ORMLite library (which is wonderful btw) but I'm a beginner using it.

I have a question about the update of the database inside the device.

Let's say that someone download my app on the Google Play. Few months later I will certainly populate some tables with new entries.

When this person is doing an update of the app, how can I just update the database with my new entries and keep the old ones inside it.

To be more clear, imagine that the user answered questions in my app. When I will introduce new questions, how can I insert them in the db when he updates my app **and keep the questions** that have already been answered ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> When this person is doing an update of the app, how can I just update the database with my new entries and keep the old ones inside it.

The idea is to use the version number that is passed to the `onUpgrade(...)` method.  With [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), the `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(...)` method takes an `oldVersion` and `newVersion` number.  You then can write conversion code into your application that is able to convert the data from the old format and update the schema.

For more information, see the [ORMLite docs on upgrading your schema](http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema).

To quote, you could do something like the following:

```
if (oldVersion < 2) {
  // we added the age column in version 2
  dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");
}
if (oldVersion < 3) {
  // we added the weight column in version 3
  dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN weight INTEGER;");
}
```

If you have existing data that you need to convert then you should do the conversions in SQL if possible.

Another alternative would be to have an `Account` entity and an `OldAccount` entity that point to the same table-name.  Then you can read in `OldAccount` entities using the `oldAccountDao`, convert them to `Account` entities, and then update them using the `accountDao` back to the same table.  You need to be careful about object caches here.

Comment: I accept this since I already managed to go through this problem by performing a switch statement on the Db version and add/remove datas according to each db version.

Comment: No problem (would be worth updating the docs example as well?) -- anyway, thank you for all your fantastic work.

Comment: Indeed.  Already updated the docs in trunk @saschoar.  They will be fixed in the next push.

Comment: Hi Gray.  It would be nice if the dao objects had some built in methods for this such as AddDateTimeColumn(ColumnName);

Comment: I'm actually struggling to figure out what data type a Joda data_time is stored as

Comment: I did not want to make a dependence on Jodatime @ChrisNevill so it is optional.   If you have questions please use the users list.  DateTime is stored in the db as a Long: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/DateTimeType.java

Answer (score 8):

I do it this way:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    switch (oldVersion) {
    case 1:
        updateFromVersion1(database, connectionSource, oldVersion, newVersion);
        break;
    case 2:
        updateFromVersion2(database, connectionSource, oldVersion, newVersion);
        break;
    default:
        // no updates needed
        break;
    }

}

private void updateFromVersion1(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // do some stuff here
    onUpgrade(database, connectionSource, oldVersion + 1, newVersion);
}

private void updateFromVersion2(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // do some stuff here
    onUpgrade(database, connectionSource, oldVersion + 1, newVersion);
}
```

This will incrementally update the users db independent from which db version he is coming.

Comment: if you remove the break sentences and move the default at the beginning you don't need to call recursively

Comment: In Room Sqlite  this way we can migrate data from old version to new version ?

Answer (score 3):

Little information, is not clear whether the changes you have table structure.

**a)** If you do not change the database structure.

1 In the new version of your program when you start checking a previously saved version (eg in preferences) 
with the current (see PackageManager.getPackageInfo)

saved = 0 - User just installed the new version

saved < current - User updates your program

2 Add new data to base

3 Save current version on preferences

**b)** If the table structure has changed (added or remove fields)

1 Increase the version number of your database (see your extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper class)

2 When the user first runs into your program, method 'onUpgrade' will be called (in your extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper class) which will be transferred to old and new version numbers.

- Read the existing data in the cache (temp)
- recreate table
- Add the data from the cache + your new data

Comment: Ok thanks for this clarifications but my question is how can I read the existing datas in the cache and add them with the new datas as you said ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't like to drop database at every upgrade, or write an update code after I add each field, so ...

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    ArrayList<String> tableNames = getTableNames(database);
    for (Class clazz : daoClasses) {
        try {
            Annotation annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(DatabaseTable.class);
            if (annotation != null && annotation instanceof DatabaseTable) {
                String tableName = ((DatabaseTable) annotation).tableName();
                if (tableName.isEmpty()) {
                    tableName = clazz.getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + clazz.getSimpleName().substring(1);
                }
                if(!tableNames.contains(tableName)){
                    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, clazz);
                } else {
                    addColumns(database, tableName, clazz);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private ArrayList<String> getTableNames(SQLiteDatabase database){
    ArrayList<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
            tableNames.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return tableNames;
}

private void addColumns(SQLiteDatabase database, String tableName, Class clazz){
    Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " LIMIT 0", null);
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            DatabaseField annotationField = field.getAnnotation(DatabaseField.class);
            if (annotationField != null && !annotationField.foreign()){
                String columnName = field.getName();
                boolean hasColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex(columnName) != -1;
                if (!hasColumn) {
                    String columnType = field.getType().getSimpleName();
                    if(columnType.equals(String.class.getSimpleName())){
                        columnType = "TEXT";
                    } else {
                        columnType = columnType.toUpperCase();
                    }
                    database.execSQL(MessageFormat.format("ALTER TABLE `{0}` ADD COLUMN {1} {2};", tableName, columnName, columnType));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mCursor.close();
}
```

I hope this code can be better.

Here, i don't delete old tables and columns that were removed from dao's, and I don't create foreign fields (I'm not sure if i need it).

Comment: Thanks! I will try it in my first Android app with SQLite + ORMLite.Is your daoClasses list defined manually like this : List<Class> daoClasses = Arrays.asList( (Class) MyDaoClass.class, (Class)AnOtherDaoClass.class) ?

Comment: you should add `if(tableName.isEmpty()) tableName=clazz.getSimpleName().substring(0,1).toLowerCase()+clazz.getSimpleName().substring(1);` after `String tableName = ((DatabaseTable) annotation).tableName(); ` in order to manage case where DatabaseTable doesn't contains any tableName (default table name is the simpleName of the class with a lowerCase first character.

Comment: @Elloco ty for improvement. Daoclasses is:
`private static final Class[] daoClasses = {A.class,B.class,C.class};`