# ORMLite database update

Tags: java, android, database, data-migration, ormlite

According to a previous question that I've asked (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782084/ormlite-update-of-the-database)), dropping and re-creating tables is not going to work very well if I make changes and add new data once I've 
distributed the app, because users will lose all their data.

Is there a recommended strategy for dealing with this and/or do you have some examples of what I have to do to manage this problem ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

It would be something like this

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //This is why I'm currently trying
        while(oldVersion < newVersion){
            switch(oldVersion){
            case 2:
                //add new datas from version 2 here
                break;
            case 3:
                //add new datas from version 3 here
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            oldVersion++;
        }
            /*
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onUpgrade");
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Category.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Level.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Hint.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, HintCount.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Question.class, true);
            // after we drop the old databases, we create the new ones
            onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
            */
    }
```

Comment: I manually add new columns to db when add new fields to objects. It seems like I'm doing ORM's job but I haven't found any other way. I check current schema and add equivalent columns so orm recognizes them.

Comment: Yes, but the problem I'm facing is to have a elegant manner to insert new entries in the db and keep the ones that have already been entered.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do? Change database - often mean change schema add/delete columns, tables. E.g. if you add new column you can set some default values to existing objects in this column in `onUpgrade`. I should admit it won't be very elegant.

Comment: Question edited. This is not really beautiful because I really don't know how can I face this problem... I was thinking about this :

1) If the user hasn't DL the app yet, onCreate method will be called and all datas will be created

2) If the user is doing an upgrade of the app, I want that my program insert only new entries and keep the old ones (but how can I do that ??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only worried about new data, not schema modification you can try `createIfNotExists` method in ORM lite. So basically on every upgrade you'll try to insert all data. But only new data will be inserted.

**EDIT:**
Another approach might be following:
Split all you objects to groups like: initial objects, first upgrade object, second upgrade objects and so on.

In `onCreate` you'll create all objects, iterating on all groups. In `onUpgrade` you'll use groups according to current version.

Comment: So you're are telling me that I have to call my method for creating datas on the onUpgrade method and call the method createIfNotExists on my daos. But my objects have an id which is auto-incremented so if I call my method which is creating my datas it will duplicates them. Right ?

Comment: I was trying that. Making a switch and iterate while oldVersion of db wasn't equals to the current version. But it complicates the process. Do you think there is a better idea ?

Comment: Ok I did the old manner with a switch and an iteration. I accept your answer as resolved cause I didn't find a better solution for the moment :( Thanks

Comment: @ZouZou did you come by any good solution to this problem? I am currently facing this problem and running out of lucks with database updates.

Comment: @Pro.metal I used a switch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782084/ormlite-update-of-the-database