# Update H2Database schema with ORMLite

Tags: h2, ormlite

I am using H2Database With ORMLite. we have 60 tables all created with ORMLite "create if not exists", Now we are going to provide a major release and requirement is to update old version database. But I need to know how to do this with ormLite as in new version some of Tables will be new and some is existing old tables with some modifications e.g we have an table of job in previous version db, in this release we added 2 more columns and change the datatype of one column. any suggestions. I have seen some other posts regarding OrmLite for Android SqlLite. How can this approach be used for other db. e.g Like this post
[ORMLite update of the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782084/ormlite-update-of-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

> But I need to know how to do this with ormLite as in new version some of Tables will be new and some is existing old tables with some modifications e.g we have an table of job in previous version db, in this release we added 2 more columns and change the datatype of one column.

I'm not sure there is any easy answer here.  ORMLite doesn't directly provide any magic capabilities to make the migration of data any easier.  Here are some thoughts however:

- You will need to use some sort of SQL logic to determine whether your application has the "old" or "new" schema installed.  You could use raw SQL to look for the existance of particular tables or columns.  Might be a good idea going forward to store a meta table with database version which Android gets for free.
- You can create new and old versions of each of your entities (`OldAccount` versus `Account`) and map them both to the same table with the `@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accounts")`.  Then you can read the old entities using the `oldAccountDao.iterator()`, convert them to new entities and (as long as you aren't mucking with the primary key) update them using the new `accountDao.update(...)`.
- You can certain come up with a series of SQL statements that will need to be performed in the proper order to change the schema.   Then call the `dao.exectuteRaw(...)` with them in order.
- Obviously the new entities will just be created.

You might want to consider dumping a backup file of all tables somewhere before the conversion process and telling the user about it in case there is some failure so your users could revert and run the old version of your application.

Hopefully something here is helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts but i managed to do this by old fashion way. i did not find any sufficient help on ORMLite. so basically I utilize JDBC API of Java to determine whether the version of DB. Then I made a SQL update script for relevant Tables and RUN over it . If success then i started the actual ORMLite Connection. By The Way Thanks