# ORMllite generic dao

Tags: android, persistence, ormlite

Here it is describe how to [Update the database with ORMLIte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16946595/2039740). But I wonder why a non-generic DAO is used to update the table. Is there any possibility for using generic DAOs to update, create or delete a table?

So instead of

```
getRuntimeExceptionDao(MyTable.class).
    executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `MyTable` ADD COLUMN mycolumn INTEGER");
```

I would like to do something like that:

```
getGenericRuntimeExceptionDao().
    executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `MyTable` ADD COLUMN mycolumn INTEGER");
```

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: this is how you update a table 

`Dao<Account, Integer> dao = getHelper().getAccountDao();
// change the table to add a new column named "age" 
dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN age INTEGER;");`   from what i see it is using a generic dao

Comment: Yes, but it is bound to the Account-Class. Do I need this binding to a class? Why should I need an Account-Dao to update the table?

Comment: you need a data access object in order perform query because all the database query functions are written into the DAOs thats why they're called Data access objects. So by taking a DAO for the account table you are able to run queries on this table and all its relations. This is by design, this is how Object to relational mapping supposed to work

Comment: I call alter table. So I do not want to run a query. I want to change the database structure.

Comment: yes its a DDL command on that particular you need the dao for that table according to ORM design pattern