# New fields in table with ORMlite without clearing the table

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a big problem, I have an application already running on dozens of smartphones, but I need to include a field in a table, to do that I always modified the version of the bank but this time I will not be able to do this because the base already has records, like Should I proceed to create only the desired field without losing the data?

Example in the transmission teb I have added the data column but it is not created unless I change the database version but I will lose all the data

Below is my DataHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "futebol.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

    private Dao<Transmissao, Integer> transmissaoDao;
    private Dao<Clube, Integer> clubeDao;
    private Dao<Configuracao, Integer> configuracaoDao;

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstace(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Transmissao.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Clube.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Configuracao.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Transmissao.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Clube.class, true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Configuracao.class, true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        onCreate(database, connectionSource);
    }

    public Dao<Transmissao, Integer> getTransmissaoDao() throws SQLException {
        if (transmissaoDao == null) {
            transmissaoDao = getDao(Transmissao.class);
        }
        return transmissaoDao;
    }
    public Dao<Clube, Integer> getClubeDao() throws SQLException {
        if (clubeDao == null) {
            clubeDao = getDao(Clube.class);
        }
        return clubeDao;
    }
    public Dao<Configuracao, Integer> getConfiguracaoDao() throws SQLException {
        if (configuracaoDao == null) {
            configuracaoDao = getDao(Configuracao.class);
        }
        return configuracaoDao;
    }

}


public class Transmissao implements Serializable {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private int idRelacao;
    @DatabaseField
    private String status;
    @DatabaseField
    private String faseRodada;
    @DatabaseField
    private String diaSemana;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Clube timeCasa;
    @DatabaseField
    private String tipoTransmissao;
    @DatabaseField
    private String hora;
    @DatabaseField
    private String nomeCapeonado;
    @DatabaseField
    private String url;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Clube visitante;
    @DatabaseField
    private String localizacao;
    @DatabaseField
    private String data;

    public Transmissao() {
    }

    public int getIdRelacao() {
        return idRelacao;
    }

    public void setIdRelacao(int idRelacao) {
        this.idRelacao = idRelacao;
    }

    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getFaseRodada() {
        return faseRodada;
    }

    public void setFaseRodada(String faseRodada) {
        this.faseRodada = faseRodada;
    }

    public String getDiaSemana() {
        return diaSemana;
    }

    public void setDiaSemana(String diaSemana) {
        this.diaSemana = diaSemana;
    }

    public Clube getTimeCasa() {
        return timeCasa;
    }

    public void setTimeCasa(Clube timeCasa) {
        this.timeCasa = timeCasa;
    }

    public String getTipoTransmissao() {
        return tipoTransmissao;
    }

    public void setTipoTransmissao(String tipoTransmissao) {
        this.tipoTransmissao = tipoTransmissao;
    }

    public String getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(String hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public String getNomeCapeonado() {
        return nomeCapeonado;
    }

    public void setNomeCapeonado(String nomeCapeonado) {
        this.nomeCapeonado = nomeCapeonado;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Clube getVisitante() {
        return visitante;
    }

    public void setVisitante(Clube visitante) {
        this.visitante = visitante;
    }

    public String getLocalizacao() {
        return localizacao;
    }

    public void setLocalizacao(String localizacao) {
        this.localizacao = localizacao;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth attempting to ask your question in English Leonardo. StackOverflow's policy is questions should be in English. Reference: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in Portuguese.

Comment: At the minimum you should use Google Translate so that you can adhere to Stack Overflow's policies. (No mínimo, você deve usar o Google Tradutor para que possa aderir às políticas do Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Maybe you wanted to post this on the Portuguese stackoverflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: Correct the question can you still help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your table, by adding/removing columns.
I think it's beed already answered here
[ORMLite update of the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782084/ormlite-update-of-the-database)